# Mutual information for two soft clustering results?

Tags: clustering

I understand that mutual information (MI) of two distributions $X$ and $Y$ is defined as

[image]

In the case of clustering analysis, say we are looking for two clusters out of 3 data points. We have two **soft** clustering algorithms and correspondingly, two cluster allocations $A$ and $B$. Let's say
$$A=\{(0.1, 0.9), (0.45, 0.55),(0.8, 0.2)\};\\B=\{(0.4, 0.6), (0.35, 0.65),(0.8, 0.2)\},$$
where $A_1=(0.1, 0.9)$ simply means that the 1st data point has a probability of 0.1 to be in cluster 1 and 0.9 in cluster 2.

In this case, how may I compute MI? In particular, how do I find the distributions (2 distributions and 1 joint distribution)?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You need MI on what ? Is it MI(A, B) ? Wouldn't you get 0 if the two algorithms are independent (I assume so) or I missed something ?

Comment: @WittawatJ. Yes, `MI(A, B)`. Essentially, the goal is to test how good `A` is assuming `B` is the ground truth, or the other way round.

Comment: I understand what you want to do. I just have a fundamental question. $I(A,B)=0$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent. I assume the two algorithms are independent. So $I(A,B)=0$. Also, you give a marginal distributions $p_A$ and $p_B$ of cluster assignments of each algorithm. This should not be enough to construct the joint $p_{AB}$. If you say $p_{AB} = p_A p_B$, then $I(A,B)=0$.

Comment: @WIJ So do you mean it is impossible to work out the MI between A and B?

Comment: You are comparing two clustering algorithms, but you would typically evaluate the quality of a clustering against some ground truth. If you have it, then you might want to consider to calculate the AUC for the results of each algorithm and compare these. If you don't want to do that, then you might have to pick or your define your own metric to compare the vectors a = (0.1, 0.45, 0.8) and b = (0.4, 0.35, 0.8). RMSE is an obvious choice but there are many others.

Comment: @WIJ how can you expect the algorithms to be independent? Say we have two algorithms to solve a linear system of equations - you can't expect their results to be indpendent in any reassonable way.

Comment: @YairDaon The two algorithms are (conditionally) independent given the problem. Are you saying that two algorithms must be dependent if they give similar results ? I think that is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you want to use some distance or divergence measure instead of MI which is a dependence measure. Presumably, your two algorithms $A$ and $B$ are independent. By this, I mean, given the clustering problem, each algorithm does not affect the other algorithm's results in any way. Hence, $p_{AB} = p_A p_B$ implying $I(A, B) = 0$.

What you want to do is to use some measure which gives you how far the result of $A$ from $B$ and vice versa. There are many measures for that. Examples include $KL(A\|B)$, Hellinger distance, or even simply rounding the probabilities to 0 or 1 and using 0-1 loss. I am sure there are some standard distances in clustering literature which I am not so familiar with.

Perhaps have a look on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Evaluation_and_assessment) in section "external evaluation". Also, check out [adjusted mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjusted_mutual_information) and [rand index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index#Adjusted_Rand_index). These two seem to be what people use to evaluate clustering results.

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't understand what you need exactly with mutual information, let me suggest a different approach.

It seems to me that you are trying to compare the performance of two algorithms $A, B$, while you believe that $B$ is, in fact, true. It might be a good idea, then, to just use $B$ all the time. But, maybe you have some restriction that prevents you from using it (e.g. it is too computationally demanding). So you might want to consider a "cheaper" algorithm. In this case, since you are already in the realm of information theory - why not use the $KL$ divergence?

You know the distribution $p_{B}(X)$:

\begin{align}
p_B(X_1 = 1) = 0.4   &\text{  ,  } p_B(X_1 = 0) = 0.6\\
p_B(X_2 = 1) = 0.35  &\text{  ,  } p_B(X_2 = 0) = 0.55\\
p_B(X_3 = 1) = 0.8   &\text{  ,  } p_B(X_3 = 0) = 0.2\\
\end{align}

and you also have $p_A(X)$. To compare them, you may calculate $\mathbb{KL}(p_B || p_A)$. The interpretation is that this is the information lost when approximating $p_B$ (which is the truth!!) using $p_A$ (which might be easier to calculate).

Answer (score 2):

It is not straightforward to define the distribution of the random variable defined by a soft clustering.

Nonetheless, it is possible to compute the mutual information between two clusterings using a trick. Let $U$ be the $r \times n$ membership matrix for the soft clustering $U$, and let $V$ be the $c \times n$ membership matrix for the soft clustering $V$:
$$
N = UV^T
$$
defines a contingency table. The mutual information can be easily computed on a contingency table.

[Generalized Information Theoretic Cluster Validity Indices for Soft Clusterings](http://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/baileyj/papers/yanglei.pdf)